# How to Proceed Javascript validation based on select box value?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code im doing ,Validation should be done  for the last two input boxes,only if select box option value is experienced

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ck_UserName =/^[A-Za-z. ]{3,20}$/;
        var ck_Emailid =/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/;
        var ck_Mobileno =/^[0-9 ]{10,11}$/;
        var ck_Age=/^[1-9 ]{1,2}$/;
        var ck_CompanyName =/^[A-Za-z. ]{3,20}$/;
        var ck_Exp =/^[0-9]{1,2}$/;
            function validate(form) 
            {
                var Empname = form.username.value;
                var Emailid = form.email.value;
                var Mobileno = form.mobno.value;
                var message = form.age.value;
                var JOB = document.getElementById('job').value;
                var Experience = document.getElementById('category').value;
                var companyname=document.getElementById('company').value;
                var Exp=document.getElementById('experience').value;
                if (JOB == "" || JOB == "option1")
                {
                    alert("Select a Job.");
                    document.getElementById('job').focus();
                    return false;
                    //errors[errors.length] = "Select a Job";
                }

                else if (!ck_UserName.test(Empname)) {
                    alert("Enter a valid Name");
                    document.getElementById('username').focus();
                    return false;
                    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid Name ";
                }
                else if (!ck_Mobileno.test(Mobileno)) {
                    alert("Enter a valid Mobile Number with 10 or 11 digits");
                    document.getElementById('mobno').focus();
                    return false;
                    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
                }
                else if (!ck_Age.test(message)) 
                {
                    alert("Enter Age");
                    document.getElementById('age').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (!ck_Emailid.test(Emailid)) {
                   alert("Enter a valid Email address .");
                    document.getElementById('email').focus();
                    return false;
                    //errors[errors.length] = " Enter a valid Email address.";
                }
            else if (Experience == 'option2' || Experience=="") {
                    alert("Select a Category.");
                    document.getElementById('category').focus();
                    return false;
                    //errors[errors.length] = "Select a Category";
                 }
                  else if (!ck_CompanyName.test(companyname)) {
                    alert("Enter a valid Company Name .");
                    document.getElementById('company').focus();
                    return false;
                    //errors[errors.length] = " Enter a valid Email address.";
                }
                else if (!ck_Exp.test(Exp)) {
                    alert("Enter Your Years Of Experience");
                    document.getElementById('experience').focus();
                    return false;
                    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
                }
            }
    </script>
```

my form is as below:

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit="return validate(this);" id ="form" name="form">
<select id="job" name="job" style="width:200px;" >
<option  value="option1" />Please select one</option>
 <option  value="Internship Program" <?php if ($_POST['job'] == 'Internship Program') 
print 'selected '; ?>/>Internship Program</option>
<option  value="Expert Web Developers" <?php if ($_POST['job'] == 
'Expert Web   Developers')print 'selected '; ?>/>Expert Web Developers</option>
<option  value="Experienced PHP Developers"<?php if ($_POST['job'] == 'Experienced PHP Developers')print 'selected '; ?>/>Experienced PHP Developers</option>
  </select>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $valid_Username; ?>" id="username" 
name="username"     style="width:200px;"/>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $valid_Mobileno; ?>" id="mobno"  
name="mobno" style="width:200px;" />

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $valid_Age; ?>" id="age" 
name="age" style="width:200px;"/>

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" <?php if(isset($_POST['sex'])
&& $_POST['sex']=='male'){ echo 'checked';} ?>/>&nbsp; Male&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" <?php if(isset($_POST['sex'])
&& $_POST['sex']=='female'){ echo 'checked';} ?>/> &nbsp;Female&nbsp;

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $valid_Emailid; ?>"  id="email" 
name="email" style="width:200px;"/>

<select id="category" name="category" onChange="return toggle1();" style="width:200px;">
<option  value="option2"/>Please select one</option>
<option  value="Fresher" />Fresher</option>
<option  value="Experienced"/>Experienced</option>
</select>

<div id="option"></div>
<div id="Fresher">
</div>
<div id="Experienced1" style="display:none;">
<div  style="height:50px;">
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" value="<?php echo $valid_Company; ?>"/>
<input type="text" id="experience" name="experience" value="<?php echo $valid_Exp; ?>"/>
<input class="submitbutton" type="submit" class="button" value="submit" name="submit" />                        
</form>
```

I no need validation for the last two input box if user clicks fresher option.Please help me

Comment: Reformat all your code to use less spacing for tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the HTML5 attribute: required
This attribute forces the user to check at least one checkbox.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Code for validating select box value is:-

```
function fun1()
{ 
if(document.f1.t4.selectedIndex==0)
{ 
document.f1.t4.focus(); //focus that select box
var para=document.getElementById('i');para.setAttribute("style","color:red;");
para.innerHTML="Try again" //display error message at label "i" position

}
else
document.getElementById('i').innerHTML=""; 

}
```

or use this:-

```
 var ddl = document.getElementById('deg');
 if( ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value == "-") flag = 1; //flag is a check variable with        initial value 0
```